# WPF and custom rendering

Tags: wpf, xaml, f#

I'm trying a very simple example in F# and WPF. I want to override OnRender on Canvas.
I did this :

```
namespace App

open ...

type public MyRender =
  class
    inherit FrameworkElement

    new() = { inherit FrameworkElement() }

    override this.OnRender(dc:DrawingContext) =
      dc.DrawRectangle(Brushes.DarkGray, null, new Rect(0.0, 0.0, 200.0, 80.0))
      let text = new FormattedText("Hello World!", 
                                   CultureInfo.CurrentUICulture,
                                   FlowDirection.LeftToRight,
                                   new Typeface("Tahoma"), 20.0, Brushes.White)
      dc.DrawText(text, new Point(30.0, 25.0))
      dc.DrawEllipse(new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Black), 
                     new Pen(Brushes.Blue, 10.0), 
                     new Point(256.0, 256.0), 80.0, 30.0)
      base.OnRender(dc)
  end

module Main = 
  type MainWindow = XAML<"MainWindow.xaml">
  let loadWindow() =
    let window = MainWindow()
    window.Root

  [<;STAThread>;]
  (new Application()).Run(loadWindow()) |> ignore
```

And in the XAML file :

```
<Window x:Class="System.Windows.Window"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
              mc:Ignorable="d"
        xmlns:wf="clr-namespace:App"
        Title="" Height="450" Width="500">
        <Canvas Height="400" Width="400">
        <wf:MyRender Width="300" Height="300"/>
        </Canvas>
</Window>
```

The name of the application is App.fs.
XAML keeps telling me MyRender is not found in App namespace. I can't uderstand why or what I can do to fix it. Could someone enlighten me ?

Thanks in advance.

[Edit] I have edited the code using the suggestion by [Tomas Petricek](https://stackoverflow.com/users/33518/tomas-petricek). I have also moved MyRender to inherit from FrameworkElement and put it into a Canvas. Now, the XAML Window in VS2013 shows the MyRender element. However I still get the run time exception about being unable to create the unkown type '{clr-namespace:App}MyRender'.

The problem seems to be now that I need to point the ws: namespace to the current assembly. 
Any idea on how to do that?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming there is nothing else in the `App.fs` file you posted, the problem could be that the file is (implicitly) compiled into a *module* named `App` rather than a *namespace* named `App` (a module appears as a static class, so your `MyRender` would be actually a nested class).

Try adding `namespace` declaration to the top:

```
namespace App

type MyRender() =
  inherit Canvas()
  override this.OnRender(dc:DrawingContext) =
    (...)

type MainWindow = XAML<"MainWindow.xaml">

module Main = 
  let loadWindow() =
    let window = MainWindow()
    window.Root

  [<STAThread>]
  do (new Application()).Run(loadWindow()) |> ignore
```

I also slightly simplified the definition of the `MyRender` class and added module to hold the entry-point code. Note that I have not actually tried this - so no guarantees!

Comment: Thanks for your answer. This is likely to be about the naming, yes. I modified the code as per your suggestion, but I still get:

Exception:Thrown: "Unable to create the unknown type '{clr-namespace:App}MyRender'." (System.Xaml.XamlObjectWriterException)

at runtime. If it is not the naming, could that be the F# XAML type provider? I hope not.